# How to return created entity id from jersey resource with container transactions?

Tags: jpa, transactions, jersey

Let's say a I create a new Widget entity in a POST method in a Jersey resource.  Further, this Jersey service is running under Glassfish 4, and is also an EJB, and has the container transaction management.

The last line of the POST method is something like

```
return Response.ok(widget).build();
```

If I control the transaction manually, then I will have the primary key of the new Widget after I call em.persist().  But since the container is handling the transaction, it does not commit until after I return the Response.  So the primary key is not filled in yet.

I guess I could use the annotation to handle the transaction manually, but I'm thinking there is probably a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I never used Jersey but sounds like a transaction demarcation problem, probably you could add to your DAO or database layer method @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW), this will suspend the current transaction and you will start new transaction and when method is completed automatically the transaction will commit, then the ID that you are looking for should be there. When return to the service the original transaction will be take it place again.

I don't know if this works in jersey but is JPA solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have both Rest api and dao in one Jersey Resource class.

If you put @Transactional attribute on Resource class this is not good, You should seperate the transactional in the API layer.,

Its best to seperate the layers like following:

1. Rest -API (Jersey Resource class)
2. Backend API ( API class for security/access control and invalid argument handling)
3. Service and DAO (Business code)

You should put the Transaction handling in the API layer., and use the default annotation value(Suported). It consist of typically put @Transactional at your API class.

If something goes wrong all the transaction will be aborted and rolled back i api layer.,

You wil by this ending up with having pk id on resource classes when the entity object are returned fom backend api layer.